# How to format date as a DD, Month, Year?

Tags: abap

I need to split ABAP date like

```
20091101 --> "01", "november", "2009"
```

The "01" and "2009" are trivial, but how do I get the month name (which should be localized)?

Is there a function to do that?

If there is no such function, perhaps a table with month names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the month's name in a given language using the module function '`MONTH_NAMES_GET`', passing the language as a parameter. The day (Sunday for example) can also be obtained using '`RH_GET_DATE_DAYNAME`'

Guillaume

Answer (score 3):

I think the absolute simplest way would be to apply the conversion exit LDATE to your date field. Easiest is to call function module CONVERSION_EXIT_LDATE_OUTPUT.

This would for example convert

```
20090101
```

to

```
01. January 2009
```

(Unless you need to actually have the day, month text and year in separate strings, which you seem to indicate. Anyway, maybe it will help someone else).

Answer (score 3):

This code will give you the date in the long text format like 'December 02, 2011'. You may change the code accordingly to print the date with long MONTH name.

```
DATA: LONG_DATE(20).
PERFORM GET_LONG_DATE USING LONG_DATE.
WRITE: LONG_DATE.

FORM GET_LONG_DATE USING DATE.

DATA: T_MONTH_NAMES LIKE TABLE OF T247 WITH HEADER LINE.

CALL FUNCTION 'MONTH_NAMES_GET'
 EXPORTING
   LANGUAGE     = SY-LANGU
  TABLES
    MONTH_NAMES = T_MONTH_NAMES
  .

DATA: YEAR(4)   TYPE C,
      MONTH(2)  TYPE C,
      DAY(2)    TYPE C.

YEAR = SY-DATUM+(4).
MONTH = SY-DATUM+4(2).
DAY = SY-DATUM+6(2).


READ TABLE T_MONTH_NAMES INDEX ( MONTH ).

CONCATENATE T_MONTH_NAMES-LTX ' ' DAY  INTO DATE SEPARATED BY SPACE.
CONCATENATE DATE ',' INTO DATE.
CONCATENATE DATE YEAR INTO DATE SEPARATED BY SPACE.

WRITE / DATE.

ENDFORM.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
* to get full name of the day / month also can use


          GET_MONTH_NAME ... for month and 
            GET_DATE_DAYNAME for the specific day name too
```

and other methods to get other format of the date are

- Using the WRITE statement

  ```
          data: get_date(10).  "field to store output date
  ```

  - Converts SAP date from 20130901 to 01.09.2013

    ```
        write sy-datum to get_date dd/mm/yyyy.
    ```
  - Converts SAP date from 20130901 to 01.09.13

    ```
        write sy-datum to get_date dd/mm/yy.
    ```
  - Using data manipulation techniques

    ```
    data: get_date(8).  "field to store output date
    ```
  - Converts SAP date from 20130901 to 01092013

    ```
         get_date(2)   = sy-datum+6(2).
         get_date+2(2) = sy-datum+4(2).
         get_date+4(4) = sy-datum(4).
    ```
  - Using Function modules

    ```
        data: get_date(8).  "field to store output date
    ```
  - Converts date from 20130901 to 01SEP2013

    ```
        get_date   = sy-datum.
    ```

    CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_IDATE_OUTPUT'

    ```
           EXPORTING

      input         = get_date

            IMPORTING

         OUTPUT        = get_date.
    ```

    these all the formats you can use for the specific dates/months and year

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can also export the date into the plant level country specific date format:

```
if w_country is initial.
  select single LAND1
    from T001W
    into w_country
   where WERKS eq w_the_plant.
endif.

SET COUNTRY w_country.

write w_the_date to w_export.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple FM 'MONTH_NAMES_GET'

```
CALL FUNCTION 'MONTH_NAMES_GET'
  EXPORTING
    LANGUAGE = SY-LANGU
* IMPORTING
* RETURN_CODE =
  TABLES
    month_names = it_t247
  EXCEPTIONS
    MONTH_NAMES_NOT_FOUND = 1
    OTHERS = 2
.

IF sy-subrc 0.
* MESSAGE ID SY-MSGID TYPE SY-MSGTY NUMBER SY-MSGNO
* WITH SY-MSGV1 SY-MSGV2 SY-MSGV3 SY-MSGV4.
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
PARAMETERS: P_1 TYPE SY-DATUM.

DATA : LV_DATE TYPE SY-DATUM,LV_TIME TYPE SY-UZEIT,lv_month type string.
        LV_TIME = SY-UZEIT.

DATA: YEAR(4)   TYPE C,
      MONTH(2)  TYPE C,
      DAY(2)    TYPE C.
      YEAR = P_1+0(4).
      MONTH = P_1+4(2).
      DAY = P_1+6(2).
      IF MONTH = '01'.
      lv_month = 'JAN'.


     ELSEIF Month = '02'.
     lv_month = 'Feb'.
     ELSEIF Month = '03'.
     lv_month = 'Mar'.
     ELSEIF Month = '04'.
     lv_month = 'Apr'.
     ELSEIF Month = '05'.
     lv_month = 'May'.
     ELSEIF Month = '06'.
     lv_month = 'Jun'.
     ELSEIF Month = '07'.
     lv_month = 'Jul'.
     ELSEIF Month = '08'.
     lv_month = 'Aug'.
     ELSEIF Month = '09'.
     lv_month = 'Sep'.
     ELSEIF Month = '10'.
     lv_month = 'Oct'.
     ELSEIF Month = '11'.
     lv_month = 'Nov'.
     ELSEIF Month = '12'.
     lv_month = 'Dec'.
     ENDIF.
   WRITE: '|',day NO-GAP,'-',
  lv_month NO-GAP,'-',year NO-GAP.
```

Answer (score -2):

```
data : lv_timestamp TYPE string,
         lv_str TYPE STRING.
  concatenate sy-datum sy-uzeit  into lv_timestamp.
concatenate 'C:\Users\Roopa Rani\desktop\header' '_'  lv_timestamp '.txt' INTO FILEPATH.
```

I think it's useful.